# How to add eventlistener cooldown (disable then re-enable event click) in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a rock paper scissors game in JS. 
The user chooses their input of rock/paper/scissors by clicking on their respective divs via element.addEventListener('click', ...)
The user plays vs the computer.
The results display on screen for a 3 seconds and then the screen resets.

Currently, the divs are still clickable while the results are being shown, which interrupts the result-showing process.

I would like to make it so that IF you try to click a div to input rock/paper/scissors during the result showing process (within 3 seconds after clicking), the divs are disabled such that clicking them does nothing.
Then once the 3 seconds are over, I want to re-enable the divs so that clicking them works again.

In simple terms, I want to add a cool-down to my div.addEventListener('click', ...)

```
var rock = document.getElementById("rock");

function layoutReset(){
   *reset the layout*
   ***re-enable rock.addEventListener('click')***
}
function game(){
   *play game*
   *show results*
   ***disable rock.addEventListener('click');***
   setTimeout(layoutReset(), 3000);   

}

rock.addEventListener('click', function{
   game();

})
```

Comment: Right, well what have you tried? Various ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Using a boolean variable and `setTimeout` should work.

Comment: And an link for setTimeout https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found a  solution. Create a boolean for whether or not the transition is taking place.

```
var transitioning = false;

function layoutreset(){
   *reset stuff*
   transitioning = false;
}
function game(){
   *play game*
   *show results*
   transitioning=true
   setTimeout(layoutReset(), 3000);   
}


div.onclick = function(){
   if(transitioning=false){
      game();
   };
}
```

Now the code checks if its transitioning, if it is, it doesn't do anything. If it isnt, it will change transitioning to false, then back to true after a 3 second delay.